# Is The Web's version of MVC different than traditional MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop

I've done a fair amount of work on MVC on the web, and we're learning about it in my OOP class. I'm seeing some differences, and I can't tell whether that's because the Web's version of the MVC pattern is different than the traditional one, or whether I misunderstood it.

From my understanding, The model (your flat files, RDBMS', etc) is a generic data-housing object. The View (Browser, HTML, etc) is what the user interacts with, and the controller mediates between the users actions and the data. The controller is the most domain-specific part, and it manages the views, tells the model what it needs, and tells the views what to display.

In class, we have the Views matching what I just described, the Model contains a list of the views so that it can update them when the data changes, and the controller simply maps the user's actions to calls to the model and to specific objects (which may themselves, ask the model to update the views). What ends up happening is that most of the business logic is in the model, and it's tied very heavily to the simulation or application that is being written, while the Controller is reduced to a mapping tool between commands and methods.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a non-web interface the controller handles the inputs from things like the keyboard and mouse, choosing which views to render and what changes to make in the model based on those inputs.  The view and model can be more closely related because the view can register callbacks directly with the model entities to be notified of changes and thus be updated based on changes to the model directly instead of being updated by the controller.

In the web world, views are necessarily more decoupled from the model.  It must act through the controller actions because it has no direct access (after being rendered and delivered to the browser) to the model.   The controller takes a larger role in this environment even though the only "input" it has to deal with are browser requests.  In a sense, the coupling that used to occur with the view in non-web MVC is transferred to the controller acting on its behalf.  Since there are no callbacks from the model to respond to (let's forget about "push" technologies for now), more business code is incorporated into the controller since it's the natural place to model business processes, though perhaps not validation.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding controllers in the web MVC pattern are just bridges between Models and Views, they simply grab the data from the Model and pass it on to the View. The Model and the View and independent and never talk to each other.

Comment: That's what I thought. But if you look at something like http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/images/app-archa2.gif it says that the Model notifies the views of changes, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There's an interesting distinction between MVC and "Three Tier Architecture" See this Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Comparison_with_the_MVC_architecture